# deserialize dynamically loaded class java

Tags: java, jar, classloader, classnotfoundexception, objectinputstream

I am loading in classes from a jarfile using a URLClassLoader and I then serialize objects of these classes and save it in a file. Then when I go to deserialize the classes the ObjectInputStream throws a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, and it isn't finding the classes I have loaded in dynamically. How would I deserialize the loaded in classes?

Comment: You need to deserialize the classes in a context which knows how to find these classes.

Comment: How would I do this? I've looked though the documentation for ObjectInputStream, but I can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

To use a custom ClassLoader you have to override the resolveClass method. Here is an example from the JDK source (which is not public but you can use it for inspiration)

```
/**
 * This subclass of ObjectInputStream delegates loading of classes to
 * an existing ClassLoader.
 */

class ObjectInputStreamWithLoader extends ObjectInputStream
{
    private ClassLoader loader;

    /**
     * Loader must be non-null;
     */

    public ObjectInputStreamWithLoader(InputStream in, ClassLoader loader)
            throws IOException, StreamCorruptedException {

        super(in);
        if (loader == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal null argument to ObjectInputStreamWithLoader");
        }
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    /**
     * Use the given ClassLoader rather than using the system class
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected Class resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass classDesc)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        String cname = classDesc.getName();
        return ClassFinder.resolveClass(cname, this.loader);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed, I used the basic skeleton for this and modified the resolve class method to have 'return Class.forName(classDesc.getName() , false , loader);' and it worked nicely , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

apache commons provides this in `org.apache.commons.io.input.ClassLoaderObjectInputStream`. the code is the same as what peter suggests, but public

from the javadocs:

> A special ObjectInputStream that loads a class based on a specified
>   ClassLoader rather than the system default.
>
> This is useful in dynamic container environments.